# How do I fill selectedcells from a datagridview with a string

Tags: vb.net, gridview, multi-select

I have a populated `DataGridView` with one empty column. After populating it automatically I want to select cells from the empty column and with a button click I want to fill the selected cells with a string

```
Dim value1 As String
skmTabelle.SKM2DataGridView.SelectedCells = value1
```

it says selected cells is read only? can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

`SKM2DataGridView.SelectedCells` is a collection of cells. You have to reference each of the individual cells in the collection

```
 SKM2DataGridView.Column("YOUR EMPTY COLUMN NAME").ReadOnly = False
 Dim value1 As String = "test"
 skmTabelle.SKM2DataGridView.SelectedCells = value1

 For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In SKM2DataGridView.SelectedCells
        cell.Value = value1
 Next

 'and as per @steve's suggestion
 skmTabelle.Validate() 
 skmTabelle.SKM2BindingSource.EndEdit()       
 skmTabelle.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(skmTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet)
```

Comment: thx now my problem is solved. Just for anybody else who reads this, dont forget: skmTabelle.Validate()
           skmTabelle.SKM2BindingSource.EndEdit()
      skmTabelle.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(skmTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet)